What does the HTTP message flow look like in a NextResponse.rewrite()?
The Next.js docs says the following about NextResponse.next():

Produce a response that rewrites (proxies) the given URL while
preserving the original URL.

How exactly does this work under the hood, i.e. how does the HTTP communication flow when NextResponse.rewrite(newUrl) is returned from middleware?
I am trying to understand if it actually sends a response to the browser, or if the server itself gets the content from the rewrite url, and then sends that to the client (pretending it was the content for the original requested url).
